# MVC File Upload or Navigate

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to allow a user to drop a file on a div, have the file be uploaded, and be pushed to the next page (which is currently happening). OR, click on the outer most div and be pushed to the next page (which is currently happening but the dialog for selecting a file appears and that I don't want to happen).

It seems to me that this is doable, but I'm not sure how to do it. Currently I have this code:

```
<div class="coloredContentPlain float-left dataSquares" onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "CreateJob")'" style="cursor: pointer;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CreateJob", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "upldFrm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="circle-color circle-color-background-orange" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; position: static;">
            <span class="circle-text" style="font-size: xx-large; font-weight: bold;">+</span>
        </div>

        <div class="newJobText">Start New Job</div>
        <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" class="uploadFile" type="file" autofocus="autofocus" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 256px; height: 144px;" />
        <input id="sumbitBtn" type="submit" value="Upload File" title="UploadFile" style="display: none;" />
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px;">Click or drop file here</div>
    }
</div>
```

And there is some jquery on the back end that clicks the submit button when a file is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // on file selection, click the hidden submit button
    $('#uploadFile').change(function() {
        if ($('#uploadFile')[0].files.length > 0) {
            $("#sumbitBtn").click();
        }
    });
});
```

If the user drops a file on the div, everything works fine. The file is uploaded and the user is pushed to the next page.

If the user clicks on the div, the user is pushed to the new page and the file dialog pops up, but I want them to only be redirected to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but it look like you have the form surrounded by the div where `onclick` it will redirect to the other page, which seems to be your issue when you go to click and it redirects.

Comment: I want it to redirect. I do not want the file selection dialog to pop up. I want to know how to keep the dialog from popping up.